# Print the last iteration in foreach loop

Tags: php

I have this function:

```
    function cart () {
       $i=0;
       foreach ($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
           $i++;

           if ($value >0) {
               if (substr($name, 0,5) == 'cart_') {
                   $id = substr ($name ,5 , strlen($name)-5);
                   $get = mysql_query('SELECT id,name FROM products WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$id));
                   echo $i;

               }
           }

       }
   }

?>
```

How to print last iteration ? For example: now in any added session appears 123. Can print only 3.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to delay the printing until after your loop has finished.

On each iteration through the loop you update a variable with the current value; each iteration therefore replaces the value, and after the last iteration has completed the value is that of the last iteration.

Then finally you can print the value.

However, in your code it's even simpler, since the value you are printing is merely an incrementing value, once per loop.  So you already have the value stored ($i), so just print that after your loop instead of inside your loop.